# KeyError: 'record_id' for CSV merge on record_id

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I am trying to merge 7 .csv files into 1. I have worked through most of my errors, but now have the KeyError: 'record_id'.
I am a beginner and am really just using Python for this one portion of my work.

I have successfully done this for a similar sample of data that was in excel but all the sheets were in one file. Now I have a full data set and it was provided to me in 7 separate csv files.

**I am showing a shortened version, with the initial merge of the first two files:**

```
import io as io
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, collections, csv
from os.path import basename

df = []


f0 = r'C:\PythonWorking\xxxData\SYLK_fix\FeMRExportDataFile0.csv'
f1 = r'C:\PythonWorking\xxxData\SYLK_fix\FeMRExportDataFile1.csv'


data_0 = pd.read_csv((io.StringIO(f0)))
data_1 = pd.read_csv((io.StringIO(f1)))


df = pd.merge(data_0, data_1, on='record_id', how='outer')

Final_csv = r'C:\PythonWorking\xxxData\SYLK_fix\FeMRExportDataFile0_6Merged.csv'

df.to_csv(Final_csv)

exit(0)
```

**Error message:**

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx> & C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe c:/PythonWorking/xxxData/SampleNIJJoin_V4_CSVs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/PythonWorking/xxxhData/SampleNIJJoin_V4_CSVs.py", line 32, in <module>
    df = pd.merge(data_0, data_1, on='record_id', how='outer')
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 81, in merge
    validate=validate,
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 626, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 975, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1774, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'record_id'
```

I expect the output to give me a csv that is a left join of all variables joined on record_id.

Small sample of the data: The columns (variables) will add up to over 800 when I am done.
[See Data sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtkZ5.png)

Comment: are you sure 'record_id' is in both f0 and f1?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could post a sample of how your two dataframes look like

Comment: Yes, I modified those myself. They were originally ID and that gave the SYLK file issues. So I updated them to record_id (its the first column in each file) since I needed that in the end for importing into another system anyway.

Comment: I added an image. The short snippet of the table didn't not display nicely. Does this help? Each csv essentially looks the same with different variable names, but starts with the record_id.

Comment: image added. Please see above.

Comment: Thanks to a fellow Python programmer, it looks like one of the data sources was not clean. I am investigating that further. This may not be an issue after all.